# Wait for another window to close in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that automatically checks out and updates a bunch of different branches in a git repository. Unfortunately, if an attempted merge or rebase on one branch results in conflicts, then the whole thing breaks, because after the relevant git command terminates, the batch script will then continue trying to checkout different branches without resolving the conflicts.

I tried starting git commands in a new window, but the batch script will still just wait for the git process to terminate, and then continue, providing no opportunity for user interaction. Is there any way to start a command from a batch script in a new command window, and then wait for the *window* to close, so the user can do additional work in that window, rather than simply waiting for the initially-started process to terminate?

Comment: You can use `start /wait cmd /c "command with params"`.

Comment: @soja tried that. Adding cmd /c makes no difference; the new window still closes automatically when "command with params" terminates, providing no opportunity for user input.

Comment: `/wait` makes execution halt until the window closes. `/c` automatically closes the window (`/k` keeps it open) unless presumably it's waiting for user input. Apparently it's not asking for user input in your case. Could you be more specific about what command you're running and what user input might be expected? Or perhaps you just want an error code reported so that the user can investigate manually? You might not even need to do any of this in a separate process from the original script.

Comment: git rebase or git merge. When they finish running, it is possible that the repository is left in an inconsistent state, if conflicts could not be resolved automatically, and it is then necessary for the user, after the process has terminated, to manually edit files before the parent batch script should be allowed to continue.

Comment: Does git return error codes for the different states? Maybe you can branch depending on errorlevel. `If %errorlevel% equ 0 (exit) else (...)`